# Bootstrap glyphicons misaligning on mobile with font size change

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I'm at a loss, have had this problem for a while.  Here is my css for a particular glyphicon I have positioned on top of an image:

css

```
.glyphicon-play-circle{
    font-size: 10em;
    position: absolute;
    color: #474747;
    opacity: 0.6;
    transition: opacity .3s;
    height: 201px;
    width: 201px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    z-index:99;
```

}

It looks like this in my view, the glyhpicon is rendered in a submit button for a form, the css above positions it on top of the image mentioned below:

html

```
  <div class="media" style="position:relative;">
      <!--play form-->
      <%= form_tag posts_play_path, :method => 'get', :remote => true do %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:post_id, post.id) %>
        <button type="submit" class="img-rounded glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></button>
      <% end %>
      <!-- end play form-->
      <img class="media-object img-rounded pull-left" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<%= post.image_url %>">
  </div>
```

On PC/Mac browsers, it the glyphicon is on top of the image, fitting perfectly

On mobile browsers (tested chrome and safari on iphone), it looks like this, where the glyphicon is pushed to the right depending on how much the font size is increased from the default (in this case, it's 10em, if i do not assign a font size, it sits centered and identical to pc/mac):
[image: thing2]
<sub>(source: [bayimg.com](http://image.bayimg.com/ad257f8849bf6ac27fbc8567973908a194e46676.jpg))</sub>

Anyone have any clue why this would only pop up in mobile browsers, and what i can do to fix it?

Much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding position "relative" to your background image and a z-index value. Also, I would switch the order of your elements as it make more sense:

```
<div class="media" style="position:relative;">
    <img class="media-object img-rounded pull-left" style="position:relative; z-index:1; width: 200px; height: 200px;" src="<%= post.image_url %>">

    <!--play form-->
        <%= form_tag posts_play_path, :method => 'get', :remote => true do %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag(:post_id, post.id) %>
                <button type="submit" class="img-rounded glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></button>
            <% end %>
    <!-- end play form-->
</div>
```